# Unravel this simple cryptic Unique NUMBER relationship

Tags: mathematics, cipher, no-computers, alphametic

Find GC ...it is a concatenated number

Given:

N + U + M + B + E + R  =   GC

Comment: Unique solution

Comment: why use the letters G and C in particular?

Comment: but it hasn't got a unique solution

Comment: http://www.tkcs-collins.com/truman/alphamet/alpha_solve.shtml you may use this for alphametric.

Comment: Cryptography tag must be included for unique solution..please do not remove the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This alphametic has numerous solutions. The couple I've found so far are

> $1 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 8 = 27$
>  $1 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 = 32$

All other permutations of $N, U, M, B, E, R$ also work, as addition is commutative.

---

Edit:

Assume A1Z26.

> $14 + 21 + 13 + 2 + 5 + 18 = 73$

This is a unique solution, given these constraints and the new tag.

Comment: See the tags.....

Comment: Which tags in particular?

Comment: Unfortunately, people have been editing tags without understanding the question. Original tags say only include cryptography

Comment: Updated to add a cryptographic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one:

> $1+3+4+5+6+9=28$